# Least Squares approximation for item prices

Tags: approximation, least-squares

Let's say that $A$, $B$, $C$ are different items with different values.

$R$ is a unit of currency, for simplicity I'll let it be $1$. Traders frequently trade these items on an open market. Price is determined by the laws of supply and demand.

$2A + B$ was exchanged for $C + R$.

$B + C$ was exchanged for $5A$.

$A + C + 2R$ was exchanged for $B + 4R$.

$A + B + C$ was exchanged for $6.33R$.

How is the approximate price (good deal) of each item calculated? Is using Least Squares approximation appropriate? I would have three separate equations. How would I do so?

I don't remember having learned Least Squares approximation, but I read this [PDF](http://www.math.utah.edu/~zwick/Classes/Fall2012_2270/Lectures/Lecture23_with_Pictures.pdf) and this [page](http://www.efunda.com/math/leastsquares/lstsqrzrwtxy1d.cfm) and it seemed like I can use it.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of changing $2r$ to $2R$. I surmise that that is what was meant. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, having not learned about Least Squares Approximation, it took me awhile.

This [paper](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~ma138/Spring14/Curve_fitting.pdf) helped a bunch.

Thus:

$ A = \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & -1 \\
-5 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 \end{array} \right|$

$ x = \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
A \\
B \\
C \end{array} \right|$

$ b = \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
0 \\
2 \end{array} \right|$

$Ax = b$

Using the normal equation for least squares:

$(A^T A) x = A^Tb$

I was able to get the values:

$A = 1.0440R$

$B = 2.1155R$

$C = 3.1375R$

Answer (score 0):

Solve all three for $R$

Then you will have $R = Mw$  Where $M$ is a matrix and $w$ is the weighting of each item
relative to $R$.

Your example is three equations and three unknowns so only invert the matrix $M$

if more equations than unknowns you must take the pseudo inverse of $M$.